# Unable to connect to AP on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: wireless-access-point, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to setup an access point, using Raling RT5370 USB Dongle on a Debian system, I followed the following [tutorial](http://thenewbieblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/wifi-hotspot-setup-on-ubuntu/), until "Internet connection Sharing.", I don't want to share internet, so I skip this step. After the reboot I can see the AP, but I can't connect, it seams I can't get an IP address, how can I debug on raspberry to see what's happening or where did I made the mistake?

This is my dhcpd.conf file content:

```
ddns-update-style none;

subnet 10.10.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 10.10.0.2 10.10.0.16;
        option domain-name-servers 8.8.4.4, 208.67.222.222;
        option routers 10.10.0.1;
}
```

The system log:

```
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: 
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: No subnet declaration for wlan0 (no IPv4 addresses).
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on wlan0.  If this is not what
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd:    to which interface wlan0 is attached. **
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: 
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: 
Aug 11 20:47:46 raspberrypi dhcpd: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
```

sytemlog:

```
Aug 11 21:00:23 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA 5c:0a:5b:24:43:d9 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Aug 11 21:00:23 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA 5c:0a:5b:24:43:d9 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA 5c:0a:5b:24:43:d9 IEEE 802.11: authenticated
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA 5c:0a:5b:24:43:d9 IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878201] BUG: scheduling while atomic: hostapd/1358/0x00000002
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878227] Modules linked in: aes_generic 8021q garp stp llc snd_bcm2835 snd_pcm snd_seq snd_timer snd_seq_device snd snd_page_alloc arc4 rt2800usb rt2800lib crc_ccitt rt2x00usb rt2x00lib mac80211 cfg80211
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878515] [<c00153d4>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xfc) from [<c03f9598>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878580] [<c03f9598>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x24) from [<c00216d0>] (__schedule_bug+0x74/0x80)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878621] [<c00216d0>] (__schedule_bug+0x74/0x80) from [<c03f9e00>] (__schedule+0x568/0x670)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878669] [<c03f9e00>] (__schedule+0x568/0x670) from [<c03fa4cc>] (schedule+0x58/0x70)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878708] [<c03fa4cc>] (schedule+0x58/0x70) from [<c03fa9b4>] (schedule_timeout+0x1a0/0x34c)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878745] [<c03fa9b4>] (schedule_timeout+0x1a0/0x34c) from [<c03fa2c4>] (wait_for_common+0xf0/0x1c4)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878793] [<c03fa2c4>] (wait_for_common+0xf0/0x1c4) from [<c03fa44c>] (wait_for_completion_timeout+0x1c/0x20)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878842] [<c03fa44c>] (wait_for_completion_timeout+0x1c/0x20) from [<c02dd2f4>] (usb_start_wait_urb+0xac/0xd4)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878884] [<c02dd2f4>] (usb_start_wait_urb+0xac/0xd4) from [<c02dd538>] (usb_control_msg+0xd4/0xf8)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.878962] [<c02dd538>] (usb_control_msg+0xd4/0xf8) from [<bf09eddc>] (rt2x00usb_vendor_request+0xc0/0x144 [rt2x00usb])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.879030] [<bf09eddc>] (rt2x00usb_vendor_request+0xc0/0x144 [rt2x00usb]) from [<bf09ef18>] (rt2x00usb_vendor_req_buff_lock+0x70/0x120 [rt2x00usb])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.879105] [<bf09ef18>] (rt2x00usb_vendor_req_buff_lock+0x70/0x120 [rt2x00usb]) from [<bf09f148>] (rt2x00usb_vendor_request_buff+0x78/0xbc [rt2x00usb])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.879182] [<bf09f148>] (rt2x00usb_vendor_request_buff+0x78/0xbc [rt2x00usb]) from [<bf0bc1b4>] (rt2x00usb_register_multiread+0x48/0x50 [rt2800usb])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.879274] [<bf0bc1b4>] (rt2x00usb_register_multiread+0x48/0x50 [rt2800usb]) from [<bf0ab014>] (rt2800_get_tkip_seq+0x50/0x80 [rt2800lib])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.879588] [<bf0ab014>] (rt2800_get_tkip_seq+0x50/0x80 [rt2800lib]) from [<bf0528d8>] (ieee80211_get_key+0x1a8/0x1f8 [mac80211])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.879964] [<bf0528d8>] (ieee80211_get_key+0x1a8/0x1f8 [mac80211]) from [<bf00a908>] (nl80211_get_key+0x288/0x328 [cfg80211])
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880130] [<bf00a908>] (nl80211_get_key+0x288/0x328 [cfg80211]) from [<c036c2bc>] (genl_rcv_msg+0x1f0/0x23c)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880183] [<c036c2bc>] (genl_rcv_msg+0x1f0/0x23c) from [<c036b568>] (netlink_rcv_skb+0xcc/0xe8)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880219] [<c036b568>] (netlink_rcv_skb+0xcc/0xe8) from [<c036c0c0>] (genl_rcv+0x28/0x34)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880254] [<c036c0c0>] (genl_rcv+0x28/0x34) from [<c036ae78>] (netlink_unicast+0x2c8/0x320)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880297] [<c036ae78>] (netlink_unicast+0x2c8/0x320) from [<c036b0e0>] (netlink_sendmsg+0x210/0x328)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880341] [<c036b0e0>] (netlink_sendmsg+0x210/0x328) from [<c0336cf0>] (sock_sendmsg+0xb0/0xd0)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880380] [<c0336cf0>] (sock_sendmsg+0xb0/0xd0) from [<c033713c>] (__sys_sendmsg+0x318/0x338)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880428] [<c033713c>] (__sys_sendmsg+0x318/0x338) from [<c0338c38>] (sys_sendmsg+0x4c/0x78)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi kernel: [  123.880475] [<c0338c38>] (sys_sendmsg+0x4c/0x78) from [<c000e140>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA 5c:0a:5b:24:43:d9 RADIUS: starting accounting session 5026C775-00000001
Aug 11 21:00:26 raspberrypi hostapd: wlan0: STA 5c:0a:5b:24:43:d9 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
```

hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=quadcopter
channel=1
hw_mode=g
auth_algs=1
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=1234567890
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Interface

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
 address 10.10.0.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

ifconfig

```
mon.wlan0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-0F-53-B1-13-41-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:545248 (532.4 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:53:b1:13:41  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:5 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1915 (1.8 KiB)  TX bytes:1698 (1.6 KiB)
```

Do I have to setup something else, because I can see the AP but I can't connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured your wlan0 device to operate in access point (AP) mode?  It looks like it may be configured as a wireless client, which could be why it's not getting an IP address set.  The lack of an IP address means the DHCP server doesn't have anywhere to listen to DHCP requests coming in.

Note that not all wireless devices are capable of operating in AP mode.  Can you confirm your device can act as an AP?

Comment: I just tested on Ubuntu 12.04 and it's working, I did the same configuration on the Raspberry Pi, wihtouth success

Comment: @iUngi: I would investigate why dhcpd is saying you haven't specified a subnet for wlan0.  If you run ifconfig, does wlan0 have the static IP address you have set?

Comment: I just post the output of the ifconfig,it seams that the wlan0 didn't get the static ip

Comment: @iUngi: Does it all work if you manually set the IP first with `ifconfig wlan0 10.10.0.1`?  If so, that would at least narrow down where the problem lies.